# Where should i store animation values?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have some animation in my app, and they work fine. But I'd like to modify the behaviour (for example) between phone ui and tablet ui. So where should I set the row values (such as android:duration="xxx")?

```
[...]
<translate 
     android:duration="700"
     android:fromYDelta="90%p"
     android:toYDelta="0"/>
[...]
```

According to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) , there's no preferred place.

Comment: Did you tried the `values` folder?

Comment: Not yet. Other than using my own xml file, should I use /res/values/dimens.xml?

Comment: You could use the dimensions file and provide one folder for each configuration you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should store a value you wish to be different across screen sizes in the `values` folder. So for example you could have a folder called `values` for default and one say called `values-sw600dp` and in there specify a value for your duration which is only for a screen with a smallest width of 600dp.

Then in the `values` and `values-sw600dp` you can have a file called `translation.xml` or whatever describes the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="duration">700</integer>
</resources>
```

And then where you do your animation xml:

```
<translate 
     android:duration="@integer/duration"
     android:fromYDelta="90%p"
     android:toYDelta="0"/>
```

This way you can specify different settings for different device sizes based on your folder names, just like you do with drawables.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Easy and as you said, just like I do with drawable!

Answer (score 0):

To check between whether the device is phone or a tab you can make a xml in values folder named as isTab.xml(or whatever you want) and code in that will be

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>`

and the same xml in values-xlarge folder but with value true in xml i.e.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>`

Now when it is a tab then the value-xlarge folder will be accessed. You can get the value in program by

```
boolean isTab= getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
```

and depending on the isTab value you can set the duration of animation dynamically by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619663/how-to-dynamically-adjust-the-duration-speed-of-a-tween-animation-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Well then why not making a separate .xml in _valuesxxx_ folders?

Comment: You have to make two separate folders with same xml except the boolean value.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I think @Neil's answer is easier (at least for what I want do to), check it out!