# How to make android animation with random duration time

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using simple animation to move or rotate object. Such as code below. I would like to use random duration time in continuous animation. It will be one animation or set of animations. Is there any simple way to do it ? Is there any chance to do it without stopping animation ? Many thanks for tips.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="80%p" android:toXDelta="0%" 
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration = "3000" />
</set>
```

Comment: have you read Animation docs?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer with sollution I found on the link below. This dynamically adjust duration of animation and solve my problem.

[How to dynamically adjust the duration/speed of a Tween Animation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619663/how-to-dynamically-adjust-the-duration-speed-of-a-tween-animation-in-android)